# How to manually number posts to appear first in Wordpress, then sort the rest alphabetically?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to create a page that lists custom post types alphabetically.  However, I want to be able to manually number some posts so that they appear first, in their numbered order, at the top of the page, and are then followed by the remaining, un-numbered posts, in alphabetical order by their title.  I know how to sort the posts alphabetically, it's combining this with the manual ordering that I don't know how to approach.

Does anyone know what the best way to tackle this would be?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Number In sense Do You Want It To Order By Dates 
it Can Be Done By Selecting Order Type And it That Date

or Else

If You Want To Drag And Drop The Order You Can Go With Some Plugins Present In Plugin Store
https://wordpress.org/plugins/intuitive-custom-post-order/